# Passing parameters from view to another view with another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to make a call to a REST API, passing two params to another view and another controller.

The syntax is `/api/:id/something/:id2/something`.

on the receiving end I have a factory that will process the call and pass it to the controller for that new page.

Here is what I have on the view:

```
<div>
    <table  class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <th style="padding-left: 20px;">ACN Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>ContractNumber</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th></th>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in acns">
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;"><a href="" ng-click="viewOrgList(ACNID)">{{row.ACNName}}</a></td>
            <td>{{row.ProductName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.ContractNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{row.ContractStartDate}}</td>
            <td>{{row.ContractEndDate}}</td>
            <td><a href="" ng-click="remove(row)"><i class="fa fa-times" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The controller for this view looks like this:

```
app.controller('acnController', ['$scope','$location', '$routeParams', 
 function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {

    //Passing acnId to networkOrg template to display.
    $scope.viewOrgList = function (acnId) {
        $location.path('/NetworkOrgs' + acnId);
    }

}]);
```

On the controller for the /NetworkOrgs template it looks like this:

```
app.controller('orgController', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$location', 'orgFactory', function ($scope, $routeParams, $locatoin, orgFactory) {
    //Capture routeParam id and display associated orgs
    $scope.org = $routeParams.acnId;
}]);



app.factory('orgFactory', ['$resource','$routeParams', function ($resource, $routeParams) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:16047/api/acn/:acnId/networkOrgs", { acnId: $routeParams.acnId }, {
        getOrgs: { method: 'GET', params: { acnId: '@acnId'} }
    })
}])
```

This is not working for me and I'm getting a "Bad Argument" result.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I bet you passed the argument incorrectly in the view.

You **have**:

```
ng-click="viewOrgList(ACNID)"
```

You **should have**:

```
ng-click="viewOrgList(row.ACNID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-click="viewOrgList(row.ACNID)"` instead of `ng-click="viewOrgList(ACNID)"`

and should

```
$scope.viewOrgList = function (acnId) {
    $location.path('/NetworkOrgs/:' + acnId);
}
```

instead of

```
$scope.viewOrgList = function (acnId) {
    $location.path('/NetworkOrgs' + acnId);
}
```

**try by this way**

**In route:**

```
$routeProvider.when('/NetworkOrgs/:acnId', { 
      templateUrl: 'Pages/acn/partials/network_orgs.html', 
      controller: 'orgController' 
 });
```

**in controller:**

```
app.controller('orgController', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$location', 'orgFactory', function ($scope, $routeParams, $locatoin, orgFactory) {
    //Capture routeParam id and display associated orgs
    $scope.acnId= $routeParams.acnId; // ensure that you have acnId
     orgFactory.getOrgs($scope.acnId)
      .$promise.then(function(response) {
         console.log(response);// check response by console
       });
}]);
```

**in orgFactory:**

```
app.factory('orgFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
            getOrgs: function(acnId) {
                var getOrgsById = $resource('http://localhost:16047/api/acn/:acnId/networkOrgs', {acnId: '@acnId'}, {
                        'get': {method: 'GET'} // if you expect return array from server then use 'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
                    });
                 return getOrgsById .get({acnId: acnId});
            };
}]);
```

Comment: Tired that, but am still getting bad request. On the receiving controller for the template I'm calling I am using the $resource service. Maybe something is off here. I'm using the $routeParams to capture the id being passed:

return $resource("http://localhost:16047/api/acn/:acnId/networkOrgs", { acnId: $routeParams.acnId }, {
        getOrgs: { method: 'GET', params: { acnId: '@acnId'} }
    })

Comment: At first you ensure that you have value of `$routeParams.acnId` in orgFactory

Comment: My assumption is that $routeParams.acnId is being pulled from the $route request. what would I change in what I have above?

Comment: Can you try `console.log($routeParams.acnId);` to show `acnId`  and you can try `$route.current.params` . check `console.log($route.current.params);` what you get?

Comment: I'm really appreciating the help all. shaishab, I've implemented what you have suggested, but now the route is not working:

    //Network Orgs Routes
        $routeProvider.when('/NetworkOrgs/', {
        templateUrl: 'Pages/acn/partials/network_orgs.html',
        controller: 'networkOrgController'
    });

Comment: your controller  `controller: 'networkOrgController'` but your above mentioned controller are not same  should be change by `orgController` and your route should be  `$routeProvider.when('/NetworkOrgs/:acnId'`